# Redirecting from the login page to signup page back to login page with the same parameters in the url in django

Tags: django

I may not have been descriptive in the title but what I want is that for example When a new user opens a page where login is required -->  he is redirected to login page with the login url having a next parameter to the previous page.But as he is a new user he chooses to signup by clicking on a link on the login page which takes him to signup page ,now this is where the problem comes - The signup url gets no parameter and once user signs up he is automatically redirected to login page and after he logs in he is redirected to the index page instead of the page where login was required.
This is my login view for my customer user model:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                next_page = request.POST['next']
                if next_page != '':
                    return redirect(next_page)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                next = request.POST['next']
                if next != '':
                    login_url = reverse('login')
                    query_string =  urlencode({'next': next})
                    url = '{}?{}'.format(login_url, query_string) # create the url
                    return redirect(url)
                else:
                    return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

And this is my signup view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            first_name=request.POST['first_name']
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']

            if password==cpassword:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
                    return redirect('signup')
                else:
                    user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,email=email,password=password)
                    user.save();
                    return redirect('/login/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,'Passwords not matching')
                return redirect('signup')
        
        else:
            return render(request,'signup.html')
```

So what I am wanting is that : The next paramter in login url is taken to the signup url and then taken back to the login url from where after logging in the user can be redirected to that **next** page.
I have been trying to find this out from a long time now but I wasnt able to find any solution so any help would be appreciated . Thanks